# Scipy, Numpy, Django, Docker Issue

Tags: python, django, docker, scipy, spacy

Having issues with scipy and numpy.
This code, part of a Django app, runs perfectly when run on my windows 10 system:

```
try:
    # sparse_load is a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    sparse_load = scipy.sparse.load_npz(cache)
    logger.info('Got sparse_load')
    concept_alias_tfidfs = sparse_load.astype(numpy.float32)
except:
    logger.exception('Something went wrong!' ) 
# code continues here ...
```

It also runs perfectly when running inside a docker container deployed on a Linux server.
The issue is that the type conversion (sparse_load.astype(numpy.float32)) crashes my app when running in a docker container deployed on Docker Desktop running on Windows 10.  The strange thing is that logger.exception is never executed!  I've tried other type conversions with the same result and also tried removing the astype altogether which resulted in another crash further down in the code (again w/o hitting the exception handler placed around that piece of code.

Thoughts?

Comment: And how it crashes on Docker Desktop? What's in `docker logs [container name]` ? It could be possible that it crashes not on attempt to execute code but just on  `import` attempt.

Comment: Good idea, but that's not what I see in the log:
`Got sparse_load`

Comment: Hm. So why it's crashed? I mean docker must say something about the reason of crash

Comment: The top part of `docker inspect container_name` contains: 

    "Created": "2020-10-16T15:52:48.7343631Z",
        "Path": "python",
        "Args": [
            "manage.py",
            "runserver",
            "0.0.0.0:7000"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 247,
            "Error": ""

Comment: Even though OOMKIlled is false (Killed due to Out of memory), I'll try increasing the memory allocation in docker settings and restest.

Comment: I mean `docker container logs [container name]`

Comment: And you said that it works fine on linux but not in Docker Desktop - that means that you have different linux kernels. Which is very possible reason for incompatibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223175/discussion-between-phil-o-and-alex-yu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though OOMKIlled is false (Killed due to Out of memory), I increased the memory from 2 to 8 GB on docker desktop and voila my app worked!